# execute javascript function after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, click

I have this function, which I would like to be executed after 5 seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#signInButton").trigger('click');

  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#signInButton").trigger('click');
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: thank you I have one comment, In addition to loading after 5 seconds, how would i work it so that it only load one every 2 hours and not per page.As of right now the modal appears every time the page is load, but i would like to load every 2 hours that page is load, so if i load the page now i see it, but if i load it 10 minute later i don't see it but if load this page again in 2 hours i see it or per browser session

Comment: You could probably could achieve that with cookies (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Store the server dateTime in a cookie and compare the last saved dateTime every time you load the page. If the new dateTime differs more than 2 hours, execute your function.

Answer (score 5):

Use [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#signInButton").trigger('click');
  }, 5000); // for 5 second delay 
});
```

Comment: @JonathanEtienne - see the answer - you have to use SetTimeout()

Comment: thank you I have one comment, In addition to loading after 5 seconds, how would i work it so that it only load one every 2 hours and not per page.As of right now the modal appears every time the page is load, but i would like to load every 2 hours that page is load, so if i load the page now i see it, but if i load it 10 minute later i don't see it but if load this page again in 2 hours i see it or per browser session

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#signInButton").trigger('click');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: You might want to describe why this is the correct answer.

Comment: thank you I have one comment, In addition to loading after 5 seconds, how would i work it so that it only load one every 2 hours and not per page.As of right now the modal appears every time the page is load, but i would like to load every 2 hours that page is load, so if i load the page now i see it, but if i load it 10 minute later i don't see it but if load this page again in 2 hours i see it or per browser session

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#signInButton").trigger('click');
  }, 5000);

  $("#signInButton").click(function(){
    alert("I'm clicked!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="signInButton" value="Click Me" />
```

Learn more about window's [**setTimeOut**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method

Comment: thank you I have one comment, In addition to loading after 5 seconds, how would i work it so that it only load one every 2 hours and not per page.As of right now the modal appears every time the page is load, but i would like to load every 2 hours that page is load, so if i load the page now i see it, but if i load it 10 minute later i don't see it but if load this page again in 2 hours i see it or per browser session

Comment: @JonathanEtienne, you need to describe more on what you exactly want to achieve, you may use `setInterval()` that will call your function periodically i.e. every 10 mins or something, but the way you're asking like every 2 hours it should call some function, I don't think it will be good to use JavaScript because, in between that interval if user refresh the page then your script will be reset.
Read more about setInterval() here, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp